# В браузере Mozilla Firefox всё увеличивается

Tags: firefox, вёрстка

```
<style type="text/css">
.field {
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
 color: #333;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-family: tahoma;
}
</style>

<input class="field" type="text">
```

Chrome - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1351952468-clip-199b.png

Firefox - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1351952493-clip-201b.png

Так вот, Firefox добавляет тупо 2 пикселя к height. Не пойму, как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите FireBug (плагин для FF), в хроме инструменты для разработчика установлены по-умолчанию (нажмите F12) - там можно увидеть все стили применяемые к элементу, в том числе и стандартные, которые применяет браузер.

P.S. Думаю, в вашем случае достаточно будет просто конкретно указать height в css, например height: 18px;

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте все свойства которые браузер назначает по умолчанию. Особенно line-height проверить стоит. Если виновник он, то нужно указать явно для всех браузеров одинаковый.

Comment: @Lucky, как проверить?